# Scrapy best practice for crawling paging site

Tags: python, scrapy

I am making crawler for html

Tach page has one tag like this,

`<a href="?page2">Next >> </a>`

then last page there is not this tag.

So how can I get each page ??

At first, I thought is like this, however some how last `self.start_request` is not called.

```
page = 0
def start_requests(self,page=0):
    urls = ['https://www.exmaple.com/page={0}'.format(page)]
    for url in urls:
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

def parse(self,response)
    #check if there is <a tag ??
    xlink = LinkExtractor()
    for link in xlink.extract_links(response):
        yield scrapy.Request(url=link.url, callback=self.parse_each)        

    if there is a tag:
       page = page + 1
       self.start_request(page)
```

What is the best practice for this crawling??

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure, that your `start_requests` method is executed. You are probably experiencing problems because you do not yield the result from `start_request`.

In your if statement, try this:

```py
yield self.start_requests(page)
```

Also, I personally would not use `start_requests` like this, since `start_requests` is automatically called when your spider starts. Instead of yielding from `start_requests`, yielding a request directly from `parse` with the url scraped from the page would make your code more clear.